# Lighting or Illumination removal OpenCV c++

Tags: c++, opencv

Hi I am comparing the difference between two images and getting the contours of just the difference exactly cars but changes in illumination / lighting affects my image and gets other contours what approach can i use to disregard the lighting changes. thanks in advance

Comment: very broad topic. Simplest options are to convert to YCbCr (or similar) and discard Y (luminance), or look only at high frequency information (i.e. subtract a blurred version of the image)

Comment: Looking at your other questions, you seem to be asking a lot of very vague things. I strongly suggest following some OpenCV tutorials before getting too deep into computer vision, to get a feel for what's possible if nothing else. Vision is a *huge* topic, and it's changing all the time. Right now, a lot of things which are very easy for humans are almost impossible for computers. Ignoring lighting is one of those problems.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Can I Remove Drastic Brightness Variations In A Video?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452438/how-can-i-remove-drastic-brightness-variations-in-a-video)

Comment: Why don't you try histogram equalization?