# Emgu Licence Plate recognition not working with HD pictures

Tags: c#, tesseract, emgucv

I'm using emguCV and tesseract with c# to recognize licence plates number, the picture is catched from an IP camera which is 1280x960 of size and 72 ppi, the result was negative, 
the first image : 
[image]
then i test the same programe with an image from my laptop web camera and the result was positive the plate was reconized and the number was read succsfully (the picture is 640x480 of size).
[image]
[image]
I need to know if the picture size or resolution can influence the licence late detection !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some great answers on image rectification/morphology, making the best use of `FindContours`. You basically need to find that rotation matrix that'll make the plate flat. The guy in the answers does exactly that.

[Rectangle detection / tracking using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44522012/rectangle-detection-tracking-using-opencv)

`FindContours` and `canny edge detection` would be a good try for your needs, since your image can't be HSV-filtered.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is yes, those variables can. Also the angle of the photo. If I am interpreting your pictures correctly, the one that failed was at quite an angle. The successful one is straight on. The example in the EmguCV package also uses a straight on plate. Tesseract, while very good, has limitations.

Doug

Comment: Thank you for your response, you said that Tesseract has limitations, can you suggest me a better one !? and also about EmguCV how can I adapt it with non-straight plates and if it exist a better solution it will be grateful